# Dynamic Variable Names - A Variation

Tags: android, textview, settext

This is an expansion to another question I asked about dynamic variable names which was resolved and working well.

This time I have a series of TextView elements with ids of e1z1, e1z2, e1z3, e2z1, e2z2, e2z3 etc (54 in total) and I hope you can see the naming pattern here.

What I need to be able to do, and I assume it will be an array of some sort, is to set each TextView id to a specific value (eg e1z1.setText("0");

Any suggestions as to the best way to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your other question that you are getting all of the TextView's into an array.

Once they are in that array, you can just use a for loop and go through the array setting anything you want for each of the TextView's.

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfViews; i++) {
   tv[i].setText("0");
   tv[i].setId(i + 99);
   ...etc.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As your pattern suggests, you have `e` values and then `z` values..eg: `e1z1`,`e2z2`

Thus you can use 2D array of TextViews like:

```
TextView[][] arrayOfTextViews;
```

The rows will be `e` values and columns will be `z`.